# Angular setting error dynamically based on condition

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a table where user can add new data to the table. The user opens a ne dialog and selects a value from the autocomplete. I am doing a validation when user selects a value from the autocomplete, if the user selects a value which is already present in the table I show a message the value is already present and disable the Submit button. But for some .reason the setError is not firing on the template side. Can someone please help me.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
        rawmaterial: [null, [Validators.required]],
    });
}

onProductChange(ob:MatOptionSelectionChange) {
    console.log('Product changed...');
    console.log(ob);
    this.selectedRawmaterial = ob.source.value;
    console.log('this.selectedRawmaterial ', this.selectedRawmaterial);
    let duplicateRM;
    console.log(this.data.rawMaterialList);
    if (this.data.rawMaterialList) {
        this.data.rawMaterialList.forEach(res => {
            console.log('res::',res);
            duplicateRM = res.rawmaterialid;
            console.log('duplicateRM::',duplicateRM);
            console.log(this.selectedRawmaterial.rawmaterialid + ' === ' + duplicateRM);
            if (this.selectedRawmaterial.rawmaterialid === duplicateRM) {
                console.log('Inside error for duplicate selection!!!!')
                return this.form.get('rawmaterial')?.setErrors({duplicate: true});
                //this.getErrorMessage();
            }
        });
    } else {
        console.log('this.data is empty!!');
    }
}
```

Template code

```
<mat-form-field class="full-wid mrgn-b-md" appearance="fill">
                <mat-label>{{'Raw Material ' |translate}}</mat-label>
                <input type="text"
                       placeholder="Pick one"
                       matInput
                       formControlName="rawmaterial"
                       [matAutocomplete]="rawmaterial_auto"
                       (keyup)="generateFilteredRawMaterials($event)"
                       (click)="generateFilteredRawMaterials($event)">
                <mat-autocomplete
                        autoActiveFirstOption
                        #rawmaterial_auto="matAutocomplete"
                        [displayWith]="displayFnRawMaterial"
                        >
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of rawmaterialFilteredOptions | async"
                                [value]="option" (onSelectionChange)="onProductChange($event)">
                        {{option.name}}
                    </mat-option>
                </mat-autocomplete>
                <button type="button" mat-button
                        *ngIf="this.form.get('rawmaterial').value" matSuffix
                        mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear"
                        (click)="clearRawmaterialOption()">
                    <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
                </button>
                <mat-error
                        *ngIf="form.controls['rawmaterial'].hasError('required') && form.controls['rawmaterial'].touched">
                    This field should not be empty.
                </mat-error>
                <mat-error *ngIf="form.controls['rawmaterial'].hasError('duplicate')">Raw material already
                    selected.
                </mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: if you move the `setErrors` to the top of `onProductChange`, will the error show?

Comment: where, template file or component file??